# Javascript: Upload some files synchronous from a form

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, file, synchronous

I need to upload multiple files from a form. I have an event "submit" that processes the data of the form, uploads the files and then shows a message. I need that this process syncronous to show the message when the files have been uploaded.

I have this HTML code in the form:

```
<form method="post" action="files/upload_project_file" id="upload_project_file_form" target="upload_project_file_iframe" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <input type="file" name="uploaded_file[]" class="multi" maxlength="0" accept="" />
       <input type="hidden" name="action" value="upload_project_file">
       <input type="hidden" name="id_project_files" value="" id="id_project_files">
</form>
```

And this Javascript code in the javascript Submit event:

```
        //processes data
        //...

        //Upload files
        var data = new FormData();     
        jQuery.each($('input[name^="uploaded_file"]')[0].files, function(i, file) {
            data.append('uploaded_file'+i, file);
        });

        data.append('id_project_files', $("#id_project_files").val());

        $.ajax({
            url: 'files/upload_project_file',
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            async: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                //Clear
                $('.filesToUpload').empty();
            }
        });

        //Then show the message and redirect page
        //...
```

I upload only one file but not all, I can't, I don't know why. I've seen Jquery.each runs only once.

Comment: Only one file is uploaded because there is only one `input type="file"` element.

Answer (score 0):

No, thanks "user2698878", I didn't want to use Uploadify.
Finally I changed the ajax code and it works perfectly. This is the new code:

```
var formData1 = new FormData($("#upload_project_file_form")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "files/upload_project_file",
            enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData1,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('.filesToUpload').empty();
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
```